# Reopen this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/579652/how-do-i-change-sort-add-remove-graphs-with-munin) was, I concede, initially poorly constructed.  It got an immediate downvote and garnered the necessary votes to close/hold it.

It has evolved and now I dare to differ that - how to configure detailed monitoring of a server's internal operations - is directly related to system administration and that this is the appropriate stack for it. I'm confident you'll sort me out if I'm mistaken.

I've worked on the problem for a few days and can now add a comprehensive answer;  it's really not as silly a question as it may have initially appeared; there are, imho, poor and/or undocumented bits and bobs required to get the desired results.

But I suspect it needs someone to reopen in order for me to answer it with what I've learned.  thx.

Comment: In the future you might want to avoid annotating your edits with "make it plain this is related to system admin, for whichever nazi has flagged this question as off-topic."  The question, as you originally wrote it was awful, and closing it because it was awful (or because you didn't seem to know what you were doing, which I suspect is what the other close-voters picked) was the right thing to do.  Putting questions on hold is specifically intended to give the person asking it a chance to fix it, which you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to flag the question for moderator attention and ask for a review and possible re-opening in there.

Posting on Meta is also perfectly fine; it will get attention here, but much slower than a mod flag.

If you flag for re-opening, and your flag is declined, then Meta is also the correct place to get attention to your issue.

Comment: If a closed question gets edited, it gets put in the reopen queue so coming to meta/flagging for moderator attention shouldn't be necessary in the first instance.